# SQL Server 2014 : how to get records with latest date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a tables with 2 columns, `LookUpID` and `LookUpDate`.

Some `LookUpID`s have multiple `LookUpDate`s. I want all `LookUpId`s with the latest `LookUpDate`.

The code I tried is:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT LookUpID, LookUpDate
 FROM LookUpTable
 WHERE LookUpID in ('ID1','ID2','ID3','......')
   AND LookUpDate = Max(LookUpDate)
```

That obviously doesn't work.

How do I look up IDs with the latest date?

Comment: Do you want the latest date per ID, or all the IDs that have the most recent date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`:

```
SELECT LookUpID, MAX(LookUpDate)
FROM LookUpTable
WHERE LookUpID in ('ID1','ID2','ID3','......')
GROUP BY LookUpID;
```

As an aside, it shocks me that people know `SELECT DISTINCT` before they know `GROUP BY`.  `GROUP BY` is more general, more powerful, and more fundamentally a part of SQL.  `SELECT DISTINCT` is usually just shorthand.

Comment: The code I used is:    SELECT LookUpID, MAX(LookUpDate)
FROM LookUpTable
WHERE LookUpID in ('ID1','ID2','ID3','......')
GROUP BY LookUpID;

Comment: I don't see how you can get the error.  `MAX` is a function.  From the error, it seems like you just put `SELECT LookUpID, MAX, LookupDate ...` instead of `SELECT LookUpID, MAX(LookUpDate) ...`

Comment: My Mistake. I am so sorry. I used MAX[LookUpDate] instead of Max(LookUpDate).   I used the () instead of []  and it worked. Thank you very much Gordon and @Eric

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you are using `distinct`

If I am not wrong this is your query

```
select 
  LookUpID, 
  LookUpDate 
FROM 
  [TotalQtySalesParent]
group by LookUpDate ,LookUpID
having LookUpDate =max(LookUpDate)
```

Comment: This definitely won't work.  Including `LookUpDate` in the grouping will give you multiple records for each `LookUpId`